# Paragraph ad libs-esque combinations in Python

Tags: python, combinations, scenarios, paragraphs

I have a basic paragraph such as:

Sarah went to the (location) to pick up some (item) with her best friend (person) However, they got lost and decided to go to (location 2). Then Sarah took some photos of (object) for her to show to her boss at work.

And these are the different scenarios that I want plugged in:
1. Store, eggs, Michael, the mall, the thinker statue 
2. Gym, weights, Lily, park, ducks
3. Pharmacy, medicine, Joe, carnival, elephants 
etc.

So clearly order *does* matter, and I want to fill in the blanks with each set. How can this be done in Python?

Thanks

Comment: I don't know where to start @ReblochonMasque, that's why I'm asking. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

here is to get you started, maybe you could try like this:

```
data = [[locations], [items], [persons], [other locations], [objects]...]

for i in range(how many times you need to print the story):
    print "blablabla", data[0][i], "blablabla", data[1][i], "blablabla", data[2][i].....
```

There are other ways, but until you first need to understand how that works.
Let me know if it helped :)